# Get order by using beetween two dates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

i have table as following

`id    name   categoryid   status  isdelete  start_date  end_date  showorder`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product 
 WHERE isdelete = 0 
   AND status = 1 
   AND name LIKE '%%' 
   AND categoryid = 4 
 ORDER 
    BY showorder ASC
```

now i want to bind data like

1) The data which **start_date** and **end_date** is between todays date it should be on top

2) The rest data will come using **showorder** order by field

So how can i achieve this  using one query because later i have to implement pagination also so double query is not suitable

Comment: Can't you use a Union to write two queries and combine the result to one?

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple keys in the `ORDER BY`, including an expression:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
WHERE p.isdelete = '0' AND p.status = 1 AND
      p.name LIKE '%%' AND categoryid = '4'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN getdate() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         showorder ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use more than one field after ORDER BY AS :

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE isdelete = '0' AND status = 1 AND name LIKE '%%' 
AND categoryid = '4' ORDER BY start_date DESC,end_date DESC,showorder ASC
```